# Blazor Server how to encrypt string in javascript and read result in razor component

Tags: javascript, encryption, blazor-server-side

I'm in need to retrieve a string save with javascript in the _Layout.cshtml with a simple

```
localStorage.setItem("MyString", strngValue);
```

and retrieve that value inside a Razor component.
I receive the value from an external service before anything is rendered but if I try to retrieve it I get and encryption error:

```
    var _savedString = await ProtLocalStore.GetAsync<string>("MyString");
    string SavedString = _savedString.Success ? _savedString.Value : "";
```

The error is risen at the await ... GetAsync... statement.

If I check Chorme or Edge DevTools in the Application Tab I have noticed that the string I'm saving is not encrypted, so I guess the problem is that when the Blazor Razor Component reads it it's not able to decrypt something that is not encrypted the it's expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: All you have shown us is a black box `ProtLocalStore` - try to focus the question more and provide information we can work with.

Comment: Sorry. I thought the question was clear enough. I'm reciving a token from Google Firebase "8gICLyG:APA91b...." that is a string and I'm saving it to the LocalStorage and I'm trying to retrieve this string inside a Blazor component with "@inject ProtectedLocalStorage ProtLocalStore". As stated in DevTools I see the string is not encrypted and I get an error: "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: An error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
 ---> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, ..."

Comment: You have found the problem - the string is not encrypted - what is your question? It sounds like you think the string should be encrypted in local storage, but it's not - is your question about that or about why your black box is throwing an error? or something else?#

Comment: I know that the problem is the encryption. What I don't know is how to encrypt the string before saving it in the LocalStorage in order to get it inside the razor component. What kind of encryption I need and how to perform encryption. Can you help me?

Comment: How can anyone know what sort of encryption you need - I can tell you that nothing you encrypt on the client is secure however.

Comment: I just need to get the token string received from Firebase, encrypt it in order to get the same value decrypted by the standard DataProtection used in Asp.net Core for Blazor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247005/discussion-between-reneram-and-mister-magoo).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know what kind of encryption is used in Blazor Server I resolved saving my Firebase Token that is a string in a cookie from the layout with a simple call to a javascript function found in Stackoverflow. Once I get grant from Firebase, but this can be used for any cookie.

**Note that values of cookies are NOT ENCRYPTED so they are visible in DevTools by anyone!**

```
  // cookie
  setCookie('tokenfb', currentToken, 7);
```

The setCookie function is loaded in my common.js with other fucntions:

```
// Save Cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = 'expires=' + d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';' + expires + ';path=/';
 }
```

And finally inside my Blazor component I have:

```
@inject IHttpContextAccessor _HttpContextAccessor

@code{

private string Tokenfb { get; set; }
private string cookieContent { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        // other code
        await LoadStateAsync();
        StateHasChanged();
        // other code
    }
}

private async Task LoadStateAsync()
{
    // other code

    // token FBCM
    var context = _HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
    if (context != null)
    {
        var cookies = context.Request.Cookies;
        var _tokenfb = cookies["tokenfb"];
        Tokenfb = _tokenfb.ToString();
    }
}
} // closing @code
```

The rest of the code doesn't have anything to do with the cookie but now I have my string and can use it as needed for my requirements.

Hope it helps others.